# getting an error AttributeError: 'FlashDisplayPage' object has no attribute 'label_name'

Tags: python, kivy

I am using carousel in FlashDisplayPage of my app. and I want to use label inside the carousel. I searched relevant sites and made the below code. I am new to kivy so I don't know if this is the right way. If its not how can I make it right?

And an error is also occurring here, even though I have defined label_name in FlashDisplayPage I am getting this error-AttributeError: 'FlashDisplayPage' object has no attribute 'label_name'. Why this error is showing up? how can I remove it?

here the part of the code where the error is occurring-

```
class FlashDisplayPage(Screen):
    def on_enter(self):
        Num=self.index
        card=['flash_card1.json','flash_card2.json','flash_card3.json','flash_card4.json','flash_card5.json','flash_card6.json','flash_card7.json','flash_card8.json','flash_card9.json','flash_card10.json']
        label_name='Flash Card '+ Num             #here I have defined label_name
        with open(card[Num+1]) as frfile:
            flash_data=json.load(frfile)

        for i in flash_data:

            self.ids.CarDisplay.add_widget(Label(text=i['word']+' : '+i['meaning'])) 
            # here I am adding label to carousel

    def next_one(self):
        self.ids.CarDisplay.direction='right'   # next label in carousel


    def previous_one(self):
        self.ids.CarDisplay.direction='left'    # previous label in carousel
```

here the part of kv code related to this-

```
<FlashDisplayPage>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        spacing:15
        padding: 20
        Label:
            id: l
            text: root.label_name
            sixe_hint_y: None
            height: 100

        Carousel:
            id: CarDisplay
            loop: True
            Button:
                text:'next'
                size_hint: None,.20
                width: 30
                on_press:root.next_one()
            Button:
                text:'next'
                size_hint: None,.20
                width: 130
                on_press:root.previous_one()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`label_name` is a local variable within the on_enter function, and local variables can only be accessed within the function or scope where they were created. If you want to be accessible a possible solution is to make it a property of the widget:

```
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

class FlashDisplayPage(Screen):
    label_name = StringProperty("")
    def on_enter(self):
        [...]
        self.label_name='Flash Card {}'.format(Num)
        [...]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `self.label_name` to create an instance variable instead of a local variable in `on_enter()` which has local scope only.